# How to specify default values for missing members of wcf DataContracts?

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontract

Assume I have the following data contract functioning across v1 of client and server.

```
[DataContract]
    public class Customer
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name;
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName;
    }
```

Now in I update the server to a new version of the DataContract V2 - adding a new member age

```
    [DataMember]
    public int Age = 25;
```

As per [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the above looks like it should default the member to 25 if the client hasn't specified it.

- ClientV1 (old) calls ServerV2 (new) - in this case, the client doesn't pass the new member. However I find that the data member has a value of 0 (Missing members should get the default value 25)

I found [another way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get this to work. Ensure DataMember.EmitDefaultValue=True(default).

```
[DataMember]
        public int Age;

        [OnDeserializing]
        internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
        {
            Age = 25;
        }
```

My question is why doesn't the field initializer approach work ?

Answer (score 0):

No constructors or field initializers are called during deserialization. I haven't found a documentation for the latter, but if you put a private field into the same class, which is not a `[DataMember]`, then you will notice, that this field does not get initialized either.

An approach I ended up using was defining a method to set the default values and call this method in both the constructor as well as from a `[OnDeserializing]` method.

For example (please forgive my use of VB.NET, it's what I had at hand)

```
Public Sub New()
  SetDefaults()
End Sub

' OnDeserializing happens before deserialization
<OnDeserializing>
Private Sub OnDeserializing(ByVal c As StreamingContext)
  SetDefaults()
End Sub

Private Sub SetDefaults()
  Foo = "FooValueV2"
  Bar = "BarValueV2"
  OnlyInV2 = "OnlyInV2Value"
  OnlyInV2Int = 98765
End Sub
```